# Symfony 2.x shows broken layout with clean install

Tags: symfony

I've just installed a Symfony Standard Application from scratch, and the layout is broken:

[image]

I've already did a bunch of stuff, such as clearing cache, changing directory permissions and etc, and nothing seems to work.

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Looks like the CSS is returning a 404

Comment: If you run assets:install the problem might be solved

Comment: It won't solve the problem, as I already tried it.

Comment: In Firebug you don't ave any 404 errors codes from resources? Can you copy/paste the generated html code?

Comment: please, attach screen of firebug network tab, to check if any subrequest failed. And tell what server do you use?

Comment: I think we solved this issue yesterday - see my answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm referencing Daniel's other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21841327/1832745) yesterday.

The cause for the problem was a misconfiguration of his nginx webserver. The stylesheets were served by nginx but did not include the correct mime-type for css files and were therefore ignored by the browser.

**The solution:**

**nginx**

You need to make sure your `nginx.conf` actually includes the correct mime-types.

```
http {
  include    conf/mime.types;
  # ...
}
```

... or ...

```
types { 
  # ...
  text/css css; 
}
```

**Apache:**

Make sure you have included this in your `httpd.conf` and enabled mod_mime.

```
AddType text/css .css
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the css files are missing.

Run `php app/console assets:install` and look at the output if some errors occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Always use following commands:

```
php app/console assetic:dump
```

This dumps all your assets

Then you use

```
php app/console assets:install
```

Or even a faster option

```
php app/console assets:install --symlink
```