# Symfony2: Stylesheets loaded but not applied on NGINX leading to broken error pages

Tags: css, symfony, nginx

I've just installed a fresh and clean Symfony app. I'm using NGINX as my webserver.

The stylesheets don't show a http 404 error code in devtools network-tab and i can see their content in the preview-tab correctly.

example picture:

[image]

Did someone face any issue like this? I'm guessing it might be a permission issue...

EDIT #1: Attached a picture of the chrome devtools showing the css are loaded correctly.

[image]

Comment: there is no route " / " in your routing file , check your routing file  routing.yml

Comment: Pay attention to the question. I am aware of the error, in fact I triggered the error. What I'm asking is about the error page LAYOUT, which is broken.

Comment: please include more information in the question. are you trying to run symfony from a subfolder like `domain.tld/subfolder/symfony` ? Did you run `app/console assets:install` and `app/console assetic:dump` ? Open your debug toolbar's **network** tab (i.e. chrome devtools = F12, ctrl+[) and inspect what paths symfony tries to load the stylesheets from.

Comment: I see that quite often with chrome when I just open the program and a tab is made to charge a symfony page

Comment: @nifr what do you mean with a subfolder? yes I ran the commands and the stylesheets are all correctly loaded.

Comment: i gave an example in my question - a subfolder of the actual vhost. like `localhost/subfolder`. What urls are the stylesheets expected to be found in your network tab ? (they should be marked red with a 404 status code)

Comment: They are being loaded correctly (not marked with red), I know what I'm saying. No subfolder. The address is actually the host itself.

Comment: well ... if the stylesheets were loaded correctly ... the layout would be styled , right ?

Comment: Right. But it's not. There are not errors loading the css files.

Comment: Something interesting I've found: when I try to copy the css paths and put them in the URL, the browser downloads the files instead of showing the css content. Nginx issue maybe?

Comment: And the stylesheet's response includes the actual css content, too ? can you attach a screenshot of devtool's network tab after clicking on the stylesheet and the content tab ?

Comment: It shows up the css content, yes. I'll attach the picture.

Comment: There it is. The picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure your `nginx.conf` actually includes the correct mime-types.

```
http {
  include    conf/mime.types;
  # ...
```

... or ...

```
types { 
  # ...
  text/css css;
```

Comment: Perfect! That was the exact issue!